# Losing Click when sorting DOM elements with JQuery Sort Function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I'm having a really strange problem while sorting a dynamic DOM structure and by dynamic I mean that there will be content coming in and out of the structure I'm sorting. So what I'm doing is running two functions every 500ms in order to re-order all the new DOM elements as soon as they came in.

I'm doing this because I have no way to sort the data before is in the DOM (so please save your "this is not the right way to do things" comments, I Know, I have no other option).

The sorting is working "OK" the thing is that originally all this DOM elements (basically a parent DIV with a lot of children) open a PopUp window when you click on them, as soon as I apply the sorting function nothing happens when I click on them, my guess is because the whole DOM is reordering very fast because of rerunning the sorting function all the time something get lost, I just don't know how to fix it.

Here's the JQuery for assigning priorities to each div row and then reordering elements by that priority:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        
    setInterval(function () {       
        //Incoming Chat Structure Variables
        var $incomingChatsTable, $incomingChatsRows, $incomingChatTags
        $incomingChatsTable= $("div[__jx__id*='incoming_list__list_content_container']")
        $incomingChatsRowsContainer=$("div[__jx__id='___$_194__visitor_list__incoming_list__list__content']")
        $incomingChatsRows = $("div[class*='renderers_Incoming']")
        $incomingChatTags = $( "div[__jx__id*='incoming_list__list__content'] div[class*='renderers_Incoming'] .visitorlist_tags .jx_ui_html_span:last-child .tag").toArray()        
        //Assigning Priorities Function
        function assignPriority(arrayParent) {
            for ( var i=0; i <= arrayParent.length; i++) {
                var actualRow = $(arrayParent[i])
                var minutesInQueue = $(actualRow).find('.time_cell').text().substr(0,2)
                var priorityVal = parseInt(minutesInQueue)
                var actualRowTags = $( actualRow ).find('.tag').toArray()
                $(actualRow).addClass('priorityRow')                
                for (var k=0; k <= actualRowTags.length; k++) {
                    let normalHolderTag = $(actualRowTags[k]).text().toLowerCase()
                    if (normalHolderTag === 'vip') {
                        priorityVal += 30
                        $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)                    
                    } else if ( normalHolderTag === 'rg' ) {
                        priorityVal += 20
                        $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)
                    } else if ( normalHolderTag === 'accountclosure' ) {
                        priorityVal += 10
                        $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)                    
                    } else {
                        $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)   
                    } 
                    $(actualRow).find('.numbers_cell').text(priorityVal)
                }
            }     
        }   
        //Sorting Incoming Chats By Priority
        function orderByPriority(container) {
            var myArray = container.find('.priorityRow')
            myArray.sort(function(a,b){
                contentA = parseInt( $(a).data('priority') )
                contentB = parseInt( $(b).data('priority') )  
                return (contentB - contentA)                              
            }).prependTo( container )
        }
        setInterval(function () {       
            assignPriority( $incomingChatsRows )
            orderByPriority( $incomingChatsRowsContainer )
        }, 500)
    }, 500)   
})
```

Comment: I don’t see your click handler so blindly I would say you should delegate that click event handler. ‘$(document).on(“click”,”.object”,function’ and it should be applied outside of any loop or anything like that. This usually works best for things that are dynamic .

Comment: Thanks  @imvain2. The Thing is I don't have access to that click event handler. I'm basically reverse engineering a plattform, so I don't have access to a bunch of the code.I have tried to check that it the click event get lost because the sorting is changing the indexes and maybe the click event handler is attached to that index but I have changed things manually on the dom and the popup still works on the click when I disable the sort function.

Comment: If you don't have access to the original click handler, you could make sure to remove it with `off` then just rebuild your own ignoring the original.